# How to update a column in PySpark based on other column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe having columns "CUSTOMER_MAILID", "OFFER_NAME", "OFFER_ISAPPLIED".

sample data:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|     CUSTOMER_MAILID|          OFFER_NAME|OFFER_ISAPPLIED|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|pushpendrakaushik...|Jaipur Pink Panth...|              N|
|pushpendrakaushik...|Jaipur Pink Panth...|              N|
|dr.kshitijmathur@...|                    |              N|
|spdadhichassociat...|                    |              N|
|vinod.gogia@herom...|Jaipur Pink Panth...|              N|
|prerak0401@gmail.com|                    |              N|
| garhwalsp@gmail.com|                    |              N|
|muditsharma1985@g...|                    |              N|
|  amit1185@gmail.com|Jaipur Pink Panth...|              N|
```

I want to update "OFFER_ISAPPLIED" column value with "Y" if "OFFER_NAME" column has some value, except Null.

How can i achieve it?

The output should be like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|     CUSTOMER_MAILID|          OFFER_NAME|OFFER_ISAPPLIED|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|pushpendrakaushik...|Jaipur Pink Panth...|              Y|
|pushpendrakaushik...|Jaipur Pink Panth...|              Y|
|dr.kshitijmathur@...|                    |              N|
|spdadhichassociat...|                    |              N|
|vinod.gogia@herom...|Jaipur Pink Panth...|              Y|
|prerak0401@gmail.com|                    |              N|
| garhwalsp@gmail.com|                    |              N|
|muditsharma1985@g...|                    |              N|
|  amit1185@gmail.com|Jaipur Pink Panth...|              Y|
```

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColum("OFFER_ISAPPLIED",
  when(col("OFFER_NAME").isNull(), "N").otherwise("Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.select("CUSTOMER_MAILID", "OFFER_NAME" , when(col("OFFER_NAME").isNull(),"N").otherwise("Y").alias("OFFER_ISAPPLIED"))
```

Comment: please eborate a lttle on your solution, for better understanding.